# Laravel Collection Pagination Problem on API Resource

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, pagination

The code below gives `Uncaught ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in...` error if I use pagination method of Laravel. If I use `all()`, it works fine.

```
 $articles = Models\Article::paginate(); // Eloquent collection
 return Article::collection(collect($articles));
```

**Article.php**

```
class Notification extends JsonResource
{
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return [
                'id'      => $this->resource->id,
                'title'   => $this->resource->title,
            ];
        }
    }
```

I also tried by creating a ResourceCollection and send query result to it, but it was the same.

```
Collection {#547
  #items: array:12 [
    "current_page" => 1
    "data" => array:1 [
      0 => array:10 [
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "Test"
        "body"" => "test"
      ]
    ]
    "first_page_url" => "https://localhost/api/v1/articles?page=1"
    "from" => 1
    "last_page" => 1
    "last_page_url" => "https://localhost/api/v1/articles?page=1"
    "next_page_url" => null
    "path" => "https://localhost/api/v1/articles"
    "per_page" => 15
    "prev_page_url" => null
    "to" => 1
    "total" => 1
  ]
}
```

Why does it return the page number, instead of full object? What do I miss? I checked [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#pagination) but it seems like it is handled by Laravel when I use paginate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Wrapping the query result with `collect` helper was unnecessary. It works now.